# How can I persist a user's id from a Rails back end server to a React front end server?

Tags: reactjs

I have a React app that makes requests to/from a Rails API. The code to sign a user in looks like this: 
"./actions/userActions"

```
export function signInUser(user){
var data = {email: user.email, password: user.password, remember_me: 
user.id};
return function(dispatch){
    dispatch({type: 'SIGN_IN_USER', payload: user})
    return fetch('https://fidirect-api.herokuapp.com/api/users/sign_in', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({user: data}),
    }).then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
    .then(response => console.log('Success:', response));
}
}
```

And the reducer looks like this:

```
export function usersReducer(state = {currentUser: {}, user_id: null}, action) {
switch (action.type) {

case 'SIGN_UP_USER':
  window.localStorage.setItem('id', 'action.id')
  return Object.assign({}, state, {currentUser: {id: action.id, email: action.email, password: action.password }, 
  user_id: window.localStorage.getItem('id') }) 
case 'SIGN_IN_USER': 
  return Object.assign({}, state, {currentUser: {id: action.payload.id, email: action.payload.email, password: action.payload.password }, user_id: current_user.id})
default:
  return state
}
}
```

This works fine, but I want to be able to persist the user's id that is stored on the back end (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.) to the front end, so that in the future, when I make a request for a particular user's data, I can filter the data based on the user's id, which would look something like this: 
"./reducers/assetsReducer"

```
case 'GET_ASSETS': 
  return {loading: false, assets: action.payload.filter((asset => asset.id === getState().usersReducer.user_id))};
default:
  return state;
```

}

How can I persist a user id like this in React?

Comment: "frontend server" is a contradiction in terms. The "frontend" is typically referred to as a "client". One way to persist data on the front end is with cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You used localstorage for your sign up reducer(not sure why) but you can do the same to sign in. Upon sign in save the data to localstorage, that or use react store.

[React Store](https://redux.js.org/api-reference/store)